# What is -ll gcc's flag?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-flags

I'm trying to compile a program that there is `-ll` flag but gcc can't find. What is the `l` after `-l`really a library or is this a typo? is hard find information about this on google.Such term is "vague".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-ll` means to link against [Solaris's libl lex library](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1464/libl-3lib.html) (available in `/usr/lib/libl.so`).

(The `-l` option takes the name of the library, minus the `lib` prefix and the file extension.)

Comment: Thanks very much. I can compile without this flag on linux. Can I have some problem in the final executable?

Comment: If you're on Linux, you are not using the AT&T `lex` but (most likely) `flex` instead.  There is a library for `flex` — `libfl.a` or `libfl.so` or similar — and you'd link with it using `-lfl`.  However, it provides a dummy `yywrap()` and a dummy `main()`, so you don't normally need it.  The `lex` library provides more than that, such as support for `yyreject`, so it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As in my case, `flex` by default **didn't** install `libfl` library (using Linux Mint)

So I had to install `libfl-dev` library separately

```
sudo apt install libfl-dev
```

and include a `-lfl` option instead of `-ll` in the commandline as in

```
gcc myfile.c -lfl -o myfile
```